# How to detect class difference at compile time using generics (java)

Tags: java, class, generics, compilation, functional-interface

I am using java 8 and I would like to detect subtle class differences at compile time modifying `withProperty()` header. This code is working but I would like to force a compilation error in `main()` function because `this::getInteger` returns an Integer and the second argument is a String.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class MatcherProperty<T, K> {
    public static <T, K> MatcherProperty<T, K> withProperty(
            Function<T, K> mapper,
            K expected
    ){
        return new MatcherProperty<>();
    }

    private Integer getInteger(Object object) {
        return 1;
    }

    public void main() {
        withProperty(this::getInteger, "Random string");
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid (if possible) a third argument in `withProperty()` function specifying the class type or something like this. Maybe K is translated to Object, the superclass of Integer an String. What is actually happening under the hoods? Is it possible to force a compilation error in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want `test()` to be within `MatcherProperty` ?   There seems no reason for it to be so, and if it wasn’t then you wouldn’t have this problem?  If `test()` is intended as part of unit testing this class, then it should be in the test case class (so again would be moved out)

Comment: It's just an example in order to keep everything in one class. The question still makes sense with line `withProperty(this::getInteger, "Random string");` in another file. I renamed the function to main.

Comment: With that call in another file, how did you declare the instance of MatcherProperty (and could you edit the question to show this code) ?  If you had, for example, `new MatcherProperty<String, File>” then you should be getting the compiler error.

Comment: That's the point, I did not declare any instance of MatcherProperty. As I commented to herman, this code is used with something like `assertList(listVatCodes.getVatCodes(), containsItem( withProperty(VatCode::getId, "Random string")));`. I could attach all the files but I think that the code I listed in the question is the minimal example to reproduce what I am trying to reach. It is easier with the minimal code I guess (?)

Answer (score 1):

There is no compile error in your current code because the result of the call to `withProperty` is ignored.

If you would try to assign the result like this:

```
MatcherProperty<Object, Integer> mp = withProperty(this::getInteger, "Random string");
```

then you'd get a compilation error because the `String` argument doesn't match type `K` which is `Integer` in the result.

If you would try to assign the result like this:

```
MatcherProperty<Object, String> mp = withProperty(this::getInteger, "Random string");
```

then you'd get a compilation error because the `Integer` result of the function given as first argument doesn't match type `K` which is `String` in the result.

You can only make the assignment compile by using a common super type such as `Object` or `Serializable`:

```
MatcherProperty<Object, Serializable> mp = withProperty(this::getInteger, "Random string");
```

You can't force people to assign the result of course.  You can add a `Class<K>` parameter to make them choose a class (such as `Integer.class` or `String.class`) but even then, they can just pass `Serializable.class` or `Object.class` instead:

```
public static <T, K> MatcherProperty<T, K> withProperty(
                Class<K> clazz,
                Function<T, K> mapper,
                K expected
        )


withProperty(String.class, this::getInteger, "Random string"); // doesn't compile

withProperty(Integer.class, this::getInteger, "Random string"); // doesn't compile

withProperty(Serializable.class, this::getInteger, "Random string"); // compiles
```

If you don't tell the compiler somehow what type `K` is (using class argument or assignment of the return value which is of type `K`) then it will infer the common type, `Serializable` in this case.

Comment: Thanks. This code actually is a simplification of something like this

`assertList(listVatCodes.getVatCodes(), containsItem( withProperty(VatCode::getId, "Random string")) );`
that's why I was asking to force a compilation error without the assignment, there is no assignment in the real code.

Line
`MatcherProperty<Object, Serializable> mp = withProperty(this::getInteger, "Random string");`
will compile even if we add a `Class<K>` parameter, isn't it? Would it be checked at runtime (?)

Comment: @RubénMorales like I said it would compile if you supplied `Serializable.class` or `Object.class` but not `String.class` or `Integer.class`.  See edited answer.